# How to convert a list of strings into a list of sets?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings as follows:

```
list1 = ["Hello", "Alaska", "Dad", "Peace"]
```

and i want to convert each string into a separate set.

```
list1 = [{'H', 'e', 'l', 'o'}, {'a', 'l', 's', 'k'}, {'d', 'a'}]
```

Comment: `[set(word) for word in list1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to do this:

```py
list1 = ["Hello", "Alaska", "Dad", "Peace"]
list_set = [set(word) for word in list1]
```

Comment: @KunalJain, you're welcome. If you're satisfied, please upvote and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use unpack operator `*`:

```
list1 = ["Hello", "Alaska", "Dad", "Peace"]
print ([{*item} for item in list1])
```